# Return custom has one relation if not existing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have users table which links to settings table using hasOne relation.
I was saving these settings with the default values on each user registration which he can change later.
But is there any way that I don't have to save those default values in database and just return those default settings through model if settings doesn't exist in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that i added to my User model. Now i can get all the settings through settings accessor.If saved in database it will return the relation from defaults table as defined in relation and if not in database it will create a complete relation with default properties that we want them to return like setting property in example with name **someSettingName**.

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['settings'];

/**
 * RETURN the settings of user.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return string
 */
public function getSettingsAttribute()
{
        // if no relation in db then build it
        if ($this->defaults === null)
        {
            // get the real relation
            $defaults                       = $this->defaults()->getRelated();
            // get the foreign key
            $foreignKey                     = $this->defaults()->getPlainForeignKey();
            // set foreign key
            $defaults->{$foreignKey}        = $this->getKey();
            // set the settings object's properties here
            $defaults->someSettingName      = 0;
            // result to be completely same as real collection :-)
            $defaults->created_at           = '2016-10-11 00:00:00';
            $defaults->updated_at           = '2016-10-11 00:00:00';
            // now set the relation query
            $this->setRelation('defaults', $defaults);
        }
        return $this->defaults;
}


/** Get the settings of the user. */
public function defaults()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Defaults');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the accessors method of Model.

Try this thing in your model.

```
$default; //Define your default setting   

public function getSettingAttribute($value) {
    $setting = $this->setting()->first();
    return ($setting!=null) ? $setting : $default;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jaymin that was really helpful